# Metabase - how to find question id or dashboard id from queryHash

Tags: amazon-redshift, metabase, iis-metabase

We are using Metabase to query Amazon Redshift DB.
In AWS UI queries section I can see Metabase user ID and corresponding queryHash.
`-- Metabase:: userID: 201 queryType: native queryHash: e0f499f3bc109a46cdf4e686fa06fb6379ec01265640ecc3f45365349b7c6e3f`

Now, I have to find out what is the question id and dashboard id for this queryHash? Is this possible, If yes how? 
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way that I found was by querying Metabase database. QueryHash column can be found in `query` and `query_execution` tables. It seems that only `query_execution` table has a reference to question/card.

```sql
SELECT 
    card_id
FROM
    query_execution
WHERE
    ENCODE(hash, 'hex') = 'e0f499f3bc109a46cdf4e686fa06fb6379ec01265640ecc3f45365349b7c6e3f'
```